# Multi-line field initializer in C#

Tags: c#

This is legal syntax in C#:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string _stringField = new MyStringGenerator().GetString();
}
```

But what if I want to replace `new MyStringGenerator().GetString()` with some more complex logic, like some multi-line code block? Anyway to make something like this work with field initializers directly without moving the logic to a method?

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string _stringField =
    {
        var stringGenerator = new StringGenerator();
        stringGenerator.SetSomething("bla");
        return stringGenerator.GetString();
    };
}
```

I tried using a code block enclosed by `{}`, or wrapping the code block in a parenthesis, but nothing seems to work. Would be good to know if this is possible at all. Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a constructor?

Comment: @vc74 yes, constructors would work, so would moving the logic to a method. I'm just wondering if there's any way to do it with field initializers alone

Comment: You're already offered the choice of initializers or constructors. I doubt many people see value in a third way between them.

Comment: Your `MyStringGenerator` should be parameterizable via constructor, or the method `GetString` should take a parameter (or both). It's a code smell if a factory class needs to be configured via method call.

Comment: I still don't get your issue. When your `GetString` depends on `SetSomething` being called, why not call that function in `GetString`? It seems like you have some logical issue rather than a syntactical one here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I would absolutely not recommend it, you can use an anonymous function and immediately invoke it to achieve your desired result:

```cs
class MyClass
{
    private string stringField = new Func<string>(() =>
    {
        var stringGenerator = new StringGenerator();
        stringGenerator.SetSomething("bla");
        return stringGenerator.GetString();
    })();
}
```

In my opinion a much better way to do this, is to abstract this functionality into a method.

Comment: Thanks for the creativity :) Seems that there's no way to write multi-line expressions though. Will put it in a separate method instead.